# mutate rust value between threads with crossbeam

Tags: multithreading, rust, crossbeam

I am modifiying a crate (`rust-argon2`) to some custom needs. That crate uses multithreading with scoped threads using `crossbeam`. I want to have a mutable state between threads, that may depend on each other.

The following snippet showcases the situation: `fill_memory_blocks_mt` gets some mutable state reference `state`, that will be mutated in `fill_segment` across multiple threads using `crossbeam_utils::thread::scope`. They are synced via `common::SYNC_POINTS`.

```rust
fn fill_memory_blocks_mt(context: &Context, memory: &mut Memory, state: &mut Argon2Result) {
    for p in 0..context.config.time_cost {
        for s in 0..common::SYNC_POINTS {
            let _ = scope(|scoped| {
                for (l, mem) in (0..context.config.lanes).zip(memory.as_lanes_mut()) {
                    let position = Position {
                        pass: p,
                        lane: l,
                        slice: s,
                        index: 0,
                    };
                    scoped.spawn(move |_| {
                        fill_segment(context, &position, mem, state);
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The compiler outputs following message:

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `state`
   --> src/core.rs:223:34
    |
223 |                     scoped.spawn(move |_| {
    |                                  ^^^^^^^^ value moved into closure here, in previous iteration of loop
224 |                         fill_segment(context, &position, mem, state);
    |                                                               ----- use occurs due to use in closure
    |
    = note: move occurs because `state` has type `&mut Argon2Result`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
help: consider creating a fresh reborrow of `state` here
    |
223 |                     scoped.spawn(&mut *move |_| {
    |                                  ++++++

error[E0382]: use of moved value: `state`
   --> src/core.rs:215:27
    |
212 | fn fill_memory_blocks_mt(context: &Context, memory: &mut Memory, state: &mut Argon2Result) {
    |                                                                  ----- move occurs because `state` has type `&mut Argon2Result`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
...
215 |             let _ = scope(|scoped| {
    |                           ^^^^^^^^ value moved into closure here, in previous iteration of loop
...
224 |                         fill_segment(context, &position, mem, state);
    |                                                               ----- use occurs due to use in closure
    |
help: consider creating a fresh reborrow of `state` here
    |
215 |             let _ = scope(&mut *|scoped| {
    |                           ++++++

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0382`.
error: could not compile `rust-argon2-wasm` due to 2 previous errors
```

Of course I don't want to copy `state` but use one instance for all threads. They don't overwrite fields between each other, but may depend on each other.

Comment: Please post the full error message from `cargo check`, not your IDE.

Comment: There's no `async` in the code you posted. Also, the compiler's suggestion looks like a bug, you can file a bug report.

Comment: If I change spawn to be `async`, I'm getting the following output. 

`scoped.spawn(|_| async move {
                        fill_segment(context, &position, mem, state);
});
`

Comment: `error[E0631]: type mismatch in closure arguments
    |
217 |             let _ = scope(|scoped: Scope| {
    |                     ^^^^^ --------------- found signature of `for<'r> fn(crossbeam_utils::thread::Scope<'r>) -> _`
    |                     |
    |                     expected signature of `for<'r> fn(&'r crossbeam_utils::thread::Scope<'_>) -> _`
    |
note: required by a bound in `crossbeam_utils::thread::scope`
    |
151 |     F: FnOnce(&Scope<'env>) -> R,
    |        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `scope`
`

Comment: But in the compiler error there is `async`, I don't understand.

Comment: Sorry for the confusions, some attempts got mixed up there on my end. I corrected the compiler output in the question now.